# How can I get absolute path of providing url in java

Tags: java

I want to get absolute path of url. For example, http://localhost:8080 will give me tomcat home page available in root directory. How can I get absolute path of tomcat root directory by providing its url http://localhost:8080 in java.

I found similar question but not found satisfactory answer so I am posting problem here.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `javax.servlet.ServletContext.getRealPath(java.lang.String)`, although there are some cases where it will not work.

From the [API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29):

> Gets the *real* path corresponding to the given *virtual* path.
>
> For example, if `path` is equal to `/index.html`, this method will return the absolute file path on the server's filesystem to which a request of the form `http://<host>:<port>/<contextPath>/index.html` would be mapped, where `<contextPath>` corresponds to the context path of this ServletContext.
>
> The real path returned will be in a form appropriate to the computer and operating system on which the servlet container is running, including the proper path separators.
>
> Resources inside the `/META-INF/resources` directories of JAR files bundled in the application's `/WEB-INF/lib` directory must be considered only if the container has unpacked them from their containing JAR file, in which case the path to the unpacked location must be returned.
>
> This method returns null if the servlet container is unable to translate the given virtual path to a real path.
>
> **Parameters:**
>        *path* - the virtual path to be translated to a real path
>
> **Returns:**
>   the real path, or null if the translation cannot be performed